# jQuery ui Drag&Drop in mouse position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've managed to drag and drop an object into a `div container`, although, this object is always placed in the left corner. I would like to know how can I place the object where the user has it's cursor pointer on.

The problem can be seen in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/en0wm6h7/1/).

I do understand that the solution might be in the following piece of code:

```
$clone.removeClass('label-item')
      .removeClass('ui-draggable')
      .addClass('dragIt')
      .css('height', 'auto')
      .css('width', 'auto');
```

And I would probably have to add `left` and `top` positions according to `ui.offset`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Positioning of dragged, dropped & appended items using JQuery-Ui Droppable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607275/positioning-of-dragged-dropped-appended-items-using-jquery-ui-droppable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

```
var positionX = ui.offset.left - $container.offset().left;
var positionY = ui.offset.top - $container.offset().top;

$clone.css('left', positionX + 'px')
      .css('top', positionY + 'px');
```